# I need a VBA code to select the column name with hyphen symbol in the middle

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code,

Set T = .Find("Goal Progress - As per Academy", lookat:=xlWhole)

I couldn't find this column as it has "-" in the middle. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
Set T = .Find("Goal Progress " & ChrW(45) & " As per Academy", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

the Special Characters you want to add to a string witch you cant type it like " you can Add it by it's code like following

**ChrW()(45) = -** *(hyphen)*

you can find more [here](http://asciitable.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I get runtime error "424" after using this.

Comment: welc, happy to help :)